# javascript: how to convert a variable to a function with the same name that returns the original value

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, clone

let's say I have a numeric variable (or any other type),
I want to convert this variable to a function which has the same variable name and returns the original value (without using additional variables)

```
var x=1
x=()=>x
```

this will copy x by reference, not by value, so the new x will always returns itself (i.e a function) not the original value

I reached the result using an additional variable (temp)

```
var x=1
var temp=x
var x=()=>temp
```

what I want is to copy this variable **by value**, not by reference 
I know how to copy an object to another object, but it is not the same case

note: using the same name is important for the flow of the next code (i.e: I have to use a function, if another type provided, I have to convert it to a function of the same name)

Comment: Sounds very much like an X/Y problem, but does `arguments` or `this` count as a variable in your situation? :P (I'm assuming that defining a parameter would count as a variable) Or, can you explain what the problem is with using another variable?

Comment: JavaScript only has call/pass by value, never call/pass by reference. Either way, I don't see how these concepts are related to what you want to do. You cannot have the same variable refer to two different values at the same. You have to introduce another variable one way or the other. If you want to have it more "self-contained", use an IIFE: `x = (x => () => x)(x);` (I guess technically this is an "IIAF" (immediately invoked arrow function)).

Comment: You're trying to do some thing that isn't natural for JS. It's unclear what the purpose is but it's very likely that this is XY problem, as it was already mentioned.

Comment: What's the use case for this, kindly?

Comment: all values passed to the next function must be a function
so I have to convert any non-function value to a function that returns the original value @estus

Comment: to be more clear, I'm  using this code in promises chain

Comment: Consider providing the code that shows your problem so possible answers could address the problem in more constructive way. From what you said it's not clear why a function should have the same name as a variable. It's also not clear why it's a problem that variable reference is passed.

Answer (score 2):

Just write a function:

```
function constFunction(temp) {
    return () => temp;
}
```

so that you can call it as `x = constFunction(x)`. Like every function call or assignment, this copies the value of the variable, not a reference. And no, you cannot really avoid a second variable (`temp` in this case), as you can't have `x` refer to both the function and the original value.

Comment: I don't use an extra variable, so you want me to use an extra function , anyway this is a good idea but out of my question's scope

Comment: @xxyy Well, as pointed out in the comments you cannot do with a single variable only.

Comment: I finally used a temporary variable